# R: histogram plot, number of bins = number of classes

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I am surprised that there seems to be no question about this problem. At least I haven't found any with an accurate answer.

Suppose the easy case of rolling two dices and adding the pips shown. Possible results range from 2 to 12. Now I want to plot the histogram for this event, i.e. one bin per possible number. That would make 11 bins (2,3,4,5...12)

```
# Example dataset: how often did we get "2","3", "4"(1x2, 3x3, 2x4, 4x5, 8x6, 14x7, ...)
Dice <- c(2,rep(3,3),rep(4,2),rep(5,4),rep(6,8),rep(7,14),rep(8,9),rep(9,5),rep(10,4),rep(11,1),rep(12,2))

hist(Dice,breaks=seq(2,12)) # custom breaks return 10 bins (9 breaks)
hist(Dice,breaks=11) # same for automatic breaks (and for breaks=12 or 13...)
```

What I need is a histogram plot with 11 bins - that is one bin per possible result. How can I trick R into doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `hist(Dice,breaks=seq(1.5,12.5))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hist(Dice,breaks=seq(1.5,12.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, that also explains how R arranges the bins. Thanks for the short and simple answer!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an histogram per se, but you could try this:

```
 barplot(table(Dice))
```

[image]

Comment: That is also a good idea, since it shows that the sum of pips on the dices is a discrete variable.